# Can a handlebars partial result be used as a helper's argument?

Tags: handlebars.js

Can a handlebars partial evaluation result be used as a helper's argument?

I was hoping subexpressions would do the trick, something like:

```
{{myHelper otherArgument (> myPartial)}}
```

Needles to say, this doesn't work and I've been scratching my head for other solutions for a while now...

Surely there must be some helper that can evaluate partials?

---

*[edit @ 2020-04-04]*

The background for wanting this was to be able to interpolate a partial's output into a sentence template by an internationalization hbs helper.

Though [@76484's suggestion](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1057#issuecomment-120538764) comes close to a viable solution, I've already admitted defeat because, while an answer was pending I tried recreating the partial as an hbs helper and found that no amount of `Handlebars.SafeString(...)` wrapping can prevent the result from getting escaped anyway after it was interpolated; so, short of modifying the i18n helper itself, it's not going to fly.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @76484, the partial is producing a snippet of html, basically some text constructed from the context wrapped in a `<span class="..."></span>` that I'd then like to pass-on to an internationalization template helper so it can be inserted in the right spot in a sentence.

Comment: Maybe this post will be of some help: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1057#issuecomment-120538764

Comment: @76484, imagine finding that... I really did a fair amount of searching before reaching out here but this is the first matching result I encounter.